# CSS Link-underline ist too thick in some browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, google-fonts

My links are set in "font-weight 300" and "text-transform underline". I use the Google-font "Roboto" via @import. In Chrome and Opera the underline is thick like font-weight 400. FF, Edge and IE don't have this issue.

HTML:

```
<p><a href="index.html">Zurück</a></p>
```

SCSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');

@mixin font-family-sans-serif(){  
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a, 
a:hover, 
a:link, 
a:visited, 
a:active, 
a:focus,
button{
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover, &:focus{
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

No problem in FF when hovering:

[image]

The problem in Chrome when hovering:

[image]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you give us jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2):

I often find Roboto rendering the underline to close to the text. Which I don't like in most cases (mostly on smaller font-sizes).

I usually use border or box-shadow. You can also consider using transparent color or sub-pixel (Chrome does a pretty good job at rendering sub-pixels) thickness to adjust the appearance.

But this depends on what browser support you are targeting. Some examples to give you an idea.

SCSS example with box-shadow:

```
$link-color: #0e7aef;

a {
    padding-bottom: 1px; // Distance of 'line' from link text adjust accordingly
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:focus,
    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba($link-color, 0.8);
        // box-shadow: 0 0.75px 0 $link-color; // sub-pixel example
    }
}
```